# python processing huge no of data in list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I have a program which makes a API call and gets response list ( part of the response if records exceeds no of threshold ) which means several API calls needed to get all data. I am able to store results in a list var for each call by using list extend method and at end i am writing the entire list back to disk in json file using `json.dump` method.
I have realized that data may be very huge ( GBs ) and if i continue to extend my list it may blown up my PC memory ( this is what i think).
So i am thinking to write list out put incrementally after every call to the same file ..( not sure this is possible ...writing the list to same file making sure it maintain json / list format) however i am concern if this also have same issue as everytime i have open the file which i wrote previous run in memory.

Could someone help me to find better approach if possible.

Thanks

Comment: The `pickle` module uses basically the same principles as json, only it uses compiled python objects (binary). The advantage is that it takes up much less memory space: I wrote a large dictionary in Python to both a pickle file and a json file, and while the json file was 11489 bytes, the pickle file was 5158 bytes. The downside to pickle is that it is python-specific, unlike json, which has support in many different languages.

Comment: if you could keep it as CSV then you can append new rows to file without reading previous rows from file. And later you can make some changes in data using pandas which can read CSV data partially.

Comment: Thanks let me check these options.